# Flink with 2 different S3 endpoints

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an s3 endpoint defined in my flink cluster, which is then used for `s3[a/p]://` filesystem. This filesystem is used for checkpointing and for sinking using Filesink (created with BulkFormatBuilder). Paths are then defined in cluster config yaml like `s3p://bckt/savepoints` . However, I would like to define a different S3 endpoint for checkpointing and for sinking. Is that possible ? To either have 2 same Filesystem types for different endpoints or to somehow override endpoint either for checkpoints or FileSink

I can think of replacing FileSink with a WindowFunction, which would write bulk of windowed data into file in overriden process function. Or somehow override filesink so it takes filesystem as parameter, which I'm going to look at in more detail.

I am using only DataStream API.

Answer (score 1):

See [Flink Amazon S3](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#hadooppresto-s3-file-systems-plugins) documentation. You should be able to use `s3a://<data path>` for your data sink, and `s3p://<checkpointing path>` for your checkpoints.